# python 3.X shows different input from when i hard code the string in program

Tags: python, python-3.x

have this problem that when i try connecting to an API it keeps sending me wrong signature and I realised that it is because when I read from the file, python 3 has these square brackets on it. When I hard code the API key and secret inside the program it works.

```
import requests
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
from hashlib import sha384
from io import BytesIO
import time
import json

def connect():
    f=open("Test-API.txt", "r")
    if f.mode == 'r':

        api_key =f.readline().splitlines()
        print(repr(api_key))
        api_secret =f.readline().splitlines()
        print(repr(api_secret))
        f.close()
    api_key = 'Your API Key'
    api_secret = 'Your API Secret'
    print(repr(api_key))
    print(repr(api_secret))
connect()
```

I realised the problem might be because of the square brackets cause when I used REPR i see the square brackets being printed. Is there a way to remove it?

['Your API Key']
['Your API Secret']
'Your API Key'
'Your API Secret'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the "single element lists" you see yourself, by using [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) on the result of `readline()`. What you probably ment to do, was removing the newline at the end. Thats what [`rstrip(chars)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) is for.

`splitline(..)` returns a list of split lines (doh). Just don't do that:

```
def connect():
    with open("Test-API.txt", "r") as f: 
        api_key = f.readline().rstrip('\n')   # rstrip the newline
        api_secret = f.readline().rstrip("\n") # no splitlines() here either

    print(type(api_key), api_key, sep = "\n")
    print(type(api_secret), api_secret, sep ="\n"

connect()
```

Also, use the `using ...` approach with `open(..)` - its more robust if encountering errors and autocloses your filehandle for you.